# UIScrollView - detecting scrolling vs orientation change in layoutSubviews?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, uikit, layoutsubviews

**Question** - In the "layoutSubviews" callback of a custom UIScrollView how could one detect the different of scrolling (which may not require subview re-layout) with other events such as an orientation change (which does require re-layout)?

**Background** - I want to add/remove subviews programmatically as scrolling occurs but in this case the existing views on the scrollview don't need re-layout, so I don't want to go through all these calculations.  However when an event such as orientation-change occurs I do want to recalc all positions.  So my question is aimed at finding the best approach to handle this.  In this case I do not want to use UIContainerView by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let priorLayoutSize = CGSize.zero

func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    let layoutSize = bounds.size
    if layoutSize != priorLayoutSize {
        priorLayoutSize = layoutSize
        // do full layout
    } else {
        // do incremental layout
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks Rob - do you know if this is normally where this check is done, i.e. in layoutSubviews?  wondering if I'm missing another callback I should be taking into account